# wordpress csv file help on bluk improts

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, csv

I'm trying to upload a CSV file via the importer the theme has but it doesn't allow me huge imports when I tried to upload a 1000 businesses it only uploaded 300 of it, so I thought it might be php memory limit so I defined the memory to 512, I am getting same result and when I try to upload k200 lines of CSV file it doesn't upload any thing with no errors from the system...

is there a way to adjust this or do I have to manually recreate a different database and upload it to phpmyadmin any idea guys?

Comment: I have changed the:  ini_set('max_execution_time', 200000); but with that I am getting a timeout error 'Error 524 Ray ID: 1ac3256d461d1389 A timeout occurred'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase your maximun execution time in php.ini file.

Visit: [detail info](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)

OR

You can write: `ini_set('max_execution_time', 108000);` in your php code

See, if that helps.

Comment: @guravdave I have added that line to my wp-config.php and waiting for results as i cant fine my php.ini

Comment: the computer that I'm using is running Windows 8

Comment: Now i have a timeout error 'Error 524 Ray ID: 1ac3256d461d1389
A timeout occurred'

Comment: Actually going back to the listing now i can see around 2000 of the 200K so it has increased from 300 to 2K @gauravdave

Comment: Try increasing execution time, anyways what is your file row count which you are uploading

Comment: my row count is 200006 and i have set it to 0 seconds so i guess that is unlimited now but still same problem

Comment: Try this: ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');